# MapInfo/MapBasic SQL query

Tags: sql, mapinfo, mapbasic

I've done a little bit of SQL query in MapBasic, but somehow get lost in this problem. I'm hoping that someone can help me out.

I have a table of polygons in 2 groups, F and E. F polygons are larger than E in size. Some E polygons are inside the boundary of some F polygons. Some are not.

How can I select the F polygons where there are E polygons inside its boundary?

It can be very simple, I guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have create a copy of your table to be able to join these.

Once you have made the copy, try running this query:

```
Select *
From MYTABLE, MYTABLE_COPY
Where MYTABLE.OBJ Intersects MYTABLE_COPY.OBJ
And MYTABLE.GROUP = "F"
And MYTABLE_COPY.GROUP = "E"
```

Note that this will find all the F polygons that intersect a E polygon. You can change the "Intersects" operator to "Contains Entire" to only find those polygons that have another polygon entirely within.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need:

```sql
Select * from F, E Where F.OBJ Intersects E.OBJ
```

In from-e, first put the table that you need